# Lock the concurrent reading row table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions

I have a table called "Consecutives" in SQL Server, in this table a number is stored.

I have another table "Data", where they store the records and one of the columns is a number, this number is take from "Consecutives" table.

To assign the consecutive, I read the "Consecutives" table, then increase the value by 1, and save.

The problem is that when multiple threads are executed, it does not read the current value of "Consecutives" and repeats the numbers.

How can I block the row of the table so that only one thread can read and update it at the same time and thus avoid repeating the numbers?

Comment: Hi Andres! Try using the IDENTITY property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

It is best to not have this requirement - because it means that all transactions trying to insert to `data` are serialized and blocked until previous ones commit or rollback.

Ideally you should use `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE` instead.

But neither of these guarantee consecutivity and if this is a "must have" then the best way is to do an atomic update and read the value at the same time.

Suppose you have the following setup

```
CREATE TABLE Consecutives
  (
     Scope  VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
     Number INT
  );

INSERT INTO Consecutives
VALUES     ('Data',
            76);
```

Then code to increment the value and read the result whilst blocking other transactions is below.

```
DECLARE @Number INT;

UPDATE Consecutives
SET @Number = Number+=1
WHERE Scope = 'Data';

SELECT @Number
```

This uses the `SET @variable = column = expression` semantics of [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to assign the post update column value to the variable.

This should be in the same transaction as the insert to `Data` if you want to ensure no gaps (at least in the absence of any deletes or updates to that column)